# Add an "Add New..." option to a Kendo DropDownList

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo `DropDownListFor` which populates from a DB table.  I want to add an option at the end that says "Add New..." which takes the user to a Create view for that DB table.  Is there a way to do this (preferably in the MVC Helper, not in javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible without JavaScript. If using JavaScript you need to use the [change](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#events-change) event and see if the value is equal to that last item in the list  then navigate the page. Something like this:

```
function onChangeOfDDl(e){
     if(...) { //you condition
         window.location.href = "/editRecord/" + this.value() 
         // this.value() will give you the value for the selected item or the text if no underlying value exists
    }
}
```